# How to make a component full width in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a `JPanel`, that lists a set of `Jlabel`s. I would like to make the width of each label wide as the panel's size. So it will be wide but but text stays in the left. I am using `BoxLayout` to list labels.

Here is the code:

```
public class JavaApplication78 {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel, labelsPanel;
    JLabel label;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<JLabel> labelsArray = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    Border paddingBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE);
    JScrollPane labelsScroll;
    public JavaApplication78(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        names.add(".mp3");names.add(".html");names.add(".jpeg");names.add(".mp4");names.add(".pdf");

        labelsPanel = new JPanel();
        labelsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelsPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        labelsScroll = new JScrollPane(labelsPanel);
        for(String format : names){
            label = new JLabel(format);
            //icon
            labelsArray.add(label);
            labelsPanel.add(label);
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,paddingBorder));
        }

        panel.add(labelsScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication78();
    }

}
```

Currently I could give a border around each `JLabel`. The height of labels are ok, but width need to be as wide as the parent panel.
Any idea ?

Comment: You could use `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `GridBagLayout`...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class JavaApplication78 {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel, labelsPanel;
    JLabel label;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<JLabel> labelsArray = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    Border paddingBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE);
    JScrollPane labelsScroll;

    public JavaApplication78() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        names.add(".mp3");
        names.add(".html");
        names.add(".jpeg");
        names.add(".mp4");
        names.add(".pdf");

        labelsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        labelsScroll = new JScrollPane(labelsPanel);
        for (String format : names) {
            label = new JLabel(format);
            //icon
            labelsArray.add(label);
            labelsPanel.add(label, gbc);
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, paddingBorder));
        }

        panel.add(labelsScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new JavaApplication78();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or a `JList`, but in cases like this, I tend to like using the `VerticalLayout` from the SwingLabs SwingX library

Comment: Simpler than overriding the maximum size of any component you might want to add to the panel, +1.

Answer (score 2):

BoxLayout respects the maximum size of the component and for a JLabel the maximum size is equal to the preferred size.

You can override the `getMaximumSize()` method:

```
label = new JLabel(format)
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize()
    {
        Dimension d = super.getMaximumSize();
        d.width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return d;
    }
};
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

This will then allow the label to expand horizontally to fill the width of the panel.

Or if you wanted you could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). It functions much like the BoxLayout but has a few additional features. The basic code would be:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.Y_AXIS);
rl.setFill( true );
JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel( rl );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PreferredSize` to set the dimension of the parent `JPanel` for your `JLabel`s :

```
JLabel label = new JLabel() {
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return labelsPanel.getSize();
   };
};
```

Unless you are obliged to use `BoxLayout`, maybe it's better to use `GridBagLayout` as suggested by @MadProgrammer in his comment.

**EDIT :**

You could also take a look at [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). Adding components with it is very simple :

```
labelsPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
labelsPanel.add(label, "span") // span to take the whole row width.
```

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)